# Find third Sunday of each month occur between given two dates

Tags: c#, .net

Find **third Sunday** of **each month** occur between given below **two dates**.

**Start Date:-** 07-06-2011 // dd-mm-yyyy

**End Date:-** 07-06-2012 // dd-mm-yyyy

**USE** ***C#.NET***

Comment: So did you try anything?

Comment: We don't mind helping people with their homework here, Pritesh, but we won't just give you the answer without you putting some effort into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public List<DateTime> ThirdSundayOfEachMonth( DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate )
{
  List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();
  int sundaymonthcount = 0;
  for( DateTime traverser = new DateTime(startdate.Year, startdate.Month, 1); traverser <= enddate; traverser = traverser.AddDays(1) ){
    if( traverser.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ) sundaymonthcount++;
    if( sundaymonthcount == 3 && traverser > startdate ){
      result.Add(traverser);
      sundaymonthcount = 0;
      traverser = new DateTime( traverser.Year, traverser.Month, 1 ).AddMonths(1);
    }
  }
return result;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... didn't see the homework tag there. Should have made him lingered a bit more himself first then.

Comment: Isnt using loop for such simple task too much? It could be done easly in a few mathematic operations

Comment: @Piotr - To much of what? IT can be done easy with a loop as well ;)

Comment: If you are afraid of performance, I tried it in LINQPad now, and running it for a 10 year period took 1 millisecond, so I think it should be ok.

Comment: By getting day of the week of StartDate u can get how many days left to next sunday. Then add 14 days and its 3rd sunday from StartDate. :) Its not about performance just it looks like adding 5 to number by using ++ in loop 5 times xD

Comment: well i am awaiting for the *few mathematical operation* answer

Comment: @Piotr Interesting but alas third sunday of the months needs to be considered from Day 1 of the month and one more sad thing we don't have equivalent weeks in all months

Answer (score 1):

To find 3rd sunday in month:

`var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);`

`int daysToAdd = (7 - (int)date.DayOfweek) % 7 + 14;`

`var sunday = date.AddDays(daysToAdd);`

I havent tested it but it should show general idea

Comment: `Third Sunday of each month` ?

Comment: for fixed month, if u want for each month it should be done in loop for 12 months

Comment: The question was not to find the 3rd Sunday in some month, but in a range of dates. So I guess that with your approach also, you need to throw a loop in there somewhere. But The way to find the third sunday should be fine, except that you assume that Sunday is the 7th day of the week, while in the DateTime it's the first.

Comment: i know that sunday has int value 0. Its why there is % 7 which will result in +0 - its already sunday. I didnt write whole code since its easy and should be done by person who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

```
> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
> using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using
> System.Web.UI.WebControls;
> 
> namespace vbvb {
>     public partial class _Default : Page
>     {
>         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             if (!IsPostBack)
>             {
>                 DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
>                 DateTime otherday = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
> 
>                 Calendar1.TodaysDate = today;
>                 Calendar1.SelectedDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate;
>                 Calendar2.TodaysDate = otherday;
>                 Calendar2.SelectedDate = Calendar2.TodaysDate;
> 
>                 TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
>                 TextBox2.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
> 
>                 var items1 = new List<ListItem>();
>                 items1.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
>                 items1.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Month", Value = "month" });
>                 items1.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Month + 2", Value = "2month" });
>                 items1.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Month + 5", Value = "5month" });
>                 items1.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Year", Value = "year" });
>                 drpMonths.DataSource = items1;
>                 drpMonths.DataTextField = "Text";
>                 drpMonths.DataValueField = "Value";
>                 drpMonths.DataBind();
> 
>                 var ddWeekdays = new List<ListItem>();
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Sunday", Value = "sunday" });
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Monday", Value = "Monday" });
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Tuesday", Value = "Tuesday" });
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Wednesday", Value = "Wednesday" });
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Thursday", Value = "Thursday" });
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Friday", Value = "Friday" });
>                 ddWeekdays.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Saturday", Value = "Saturday" });
>                 drpWeekdays.DataSource = ddWeekdays;
>                 drpWeekdays.DataTextField = "Text";
>                 drpWeekdays.DataValueField = "Value";
>                 drpWeekdays.DataBind();
> 
>                 var ddinterval = new List<ListItem>();
>                 ddinterval.Add(new ListItem("", ""));
>                 ddinterval.Add(new ListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
>                 ddinterval.Add(new ListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
>                 ddinterval.Add(new ListItem { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
>                 ddinterval.Add(new ListItem { Text = "4", Value = "4" });
>                 ddinterval.Add(new ListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
>                 drpInterval.DataSource = ddinterval;
>                 drpInterval.DataTextField = "Text";
>                 drpInterval.DataValueField = "Value";
>                 drpInterval.DataBind();
>             }
>         }
> 
>         protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
> 
>         }
> 
>         protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
> 
>         }
> 
>         protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
>         }
> 
>         protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             TextBox2.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
>         }
> 
>         protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             var fromDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
>             var todate = Calendar2.SelectedDate;
>             var dateList = new List<DateTime>();
>             if (fromDate != null && todate != null && (todate > fromDate))
>             {
>                 var fDate = fromDate;
>                 bool flag = true;
>                 while (fDate < todate)
>                 {
>                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpMonths.SelectedValue))
>                     {
>                         flag = CheckMonth(fDate);
>                     }
>                     if (flag && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpWeekdays.SelectedValue))
>                     {
>                         flag = CheckDay(fDate);
>                     }
>                     if (flag && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpInterval.SelectedValue))
>                     {
>                         flag = CheckInterval(fDate);
>                     }
>                     if (flag)
>                     {
>                         dateList.Add(fDate);
>                     }
>                     fDate = fDate.AddDays(1);
>                     flag = true;
>                 }
>                 BulletedList1.DataSource = dateList;
>                 BulletedList1.DataBind();
>             }
>         }
> 
>         public DateTime? LastExecutedMonth = null;
>         private bool CheckMonth(DateTime date)
>         {
>             var retVal = false;
>             if (LastExecutedMonth == null)
>             {
>                 LastExecutedMonth = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
>             }
>            
>             switch (drpMonths.SelectedValue.ToLower())
>             {
>                 case "month":
>                     if (MonthDiff(Convert.ToDateTime(LastExecutedMonth), date) == 1)
>                     {
>                         retVal = true;
>                         if (date == new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1))
>                         {
>                             LastExecutedMonth = date;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case "2month":
>                     if (MonthDiff(Convert.ToDateTime(LastExecutedMonth), date) == 2)
>                     {
>                         retVal = true;
>                         if (date == new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1))
>                         {
>                             LastExecutedMonth = date;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case "5month":
>                     if (MonthDiff(Convert.ToDateTime(LastExecutedMonth), date) == 5)
>                     {
>                         retVal = true;
>                         if (date == new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1))
>                         {
>                             LastExecutedMonth = date;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     break;
>                 case "year":
>                     if (MonthDiff(Convert.ToDateTime(LastExecutedMonth), date) == 12)
>                     {
>                         retVal = true;
>                         if (date == new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1))
>                         {
>                             LastExecutedMonth = date;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     break;
>             }
>             return retVal;
>         }
> 
>         private bool CheckDay(DateTime date)
>         {
>             var retval = false;
>             switch (drpWeekdays.SelectedValue.ToLower())
>             {
>                 case "sunday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
>                     break;
>                 case "monday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday;
>                     break;
>                 case "tuesday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
>                     break;
>                 case "wednesday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
>                     break;
>                 case "thursday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday;
>                     break;
>                 case "friday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday;
>                     break;
>                 case "saturday":
>                     retval = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday;
>                     break;
>             }
>             return retval;
>         }
> 
>         private bool CheckInterval(DateTime date)
>         {
>             var flag = false;
>             switch (drpInterval.SelectedValue.ToLower())
>             {
>                 case "1":
>                     flag = date == XthDayOfWeekInMonth(date.Year, date.Month, date.DayOfWeek, 1);
>                     break;
>                 case "2":
>                     flag = date == XthDayOfWeekInMonth(date.Year, date.Month, date.DayOfWeek, 2);
>                     break;
>                 case "3":
>                     flag = date == XthDayOfWeekInMonth(date.Year, date.Month, date.DayOfWeek, 3);
>                     break;
>                 case "4":
>                     flag = date == XthDayOfWeekInMonth(date.Year, date.Month, date.DayOfWeek, 4);
>                     break;
>                 case "5":
>                     flag = date == XthDayOfWeekInMonth(date.Year, date.Month, date.DayOfWeek, 5);
>                     break;
>             }
>             return flag;
>         }
> 
>         public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeekInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek day)
>         {
>             DateTime res = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
>             int offset = -(res.DayOfWeek - day);
> 
>             if (offset < 0)
>                 offset += 7;
> 
>             res = res.AddDays(offset);
> 
>             return res;
>         }
> 
>         public static DateTime LastDayOfWeekInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek day)
>         {
>             DateTime res = FirstDayOfWeekInMonth(year, month + 1, day);
> 
>             res = res.AddDays(-7);
> 
>             return res;
>         }
> 
>         public static DateTime XthDayOfWeekInMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek day, int x)
>         {
>             DateTime res = DateTime.MinValue;
> 
>             if (x > 0)
>             {
>                 res = FirstDayOfWeekInMonth(year, month, day);
> 
>                 if (x > 1)
>                     res = res.AddDays((x - 1) * 7);
> 
>                 res = res.Year == year && res.Month == month ? res : DateTime.MinValue;
>             }
> 
>             return res;
>         }
> 
>         public static int MonthDiff(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
>         {
>             if (date1.Month < date2.Month)
>             {
>                 return (date2.Year - date1.Year) * 12 + date2.Month - date1.Month;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 return (date2.Year - date1.Year - 1) * 12 + date2.Month - date1.Month + 12;
>             }
>         }
>     } }
```